# TSC error in cypress with pnpm workspace setup

Tags: tsc, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have the following issue when running `pnpm tsc --noEmit` from the root folder of my monorepo setup with workspaces:

> Property 'to' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<JQuery>'

The offending line of code is:

```
expect(something).to.include(somethingElse);
```

This was not an issue before when I used yarn workspaces, but only became one when switching to pnpm.

My repo structure looks like this:

```
- root/
  - package.json
  - packages/
    - sub-package/
      - tests/
          - test.cy.ts (file that has the error)
      - package.json ("cypress" listed here)
```

I also added this to `.npmrc` which had no effect:

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*@types*
public-hoist-pattern[]=cypress
```

And included `cypress` in my tscfonig `"types"`.
My IDE takes me to

```
node_modules/.pnpm/cypress@12.1.0/node_modules/cypress/types/chai/index.d.ts
```

when I check the definition of "to", I also checked again with yarn, and it takes me to:

```
node_modules/cypress/types/chai/index.d.ts
```

How can this be resolved?